# Error on expected a statement on if and else statement

Tags: c++

In my comparison problem, I used an if and else statement, so I am getting an error on it.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    double lgt, hgt, lgt1, hgt1, x, y;

    cout << "enter the length of retangle 1= ";
    cin >> lgt;
    cout << "Enter the height of rectangle 1= ";
    cin >> hgt;
    cout << "enter the length of rectangle 2= ";
    cin >> lgt1;
    cout << "enter the height of rectangle 2= ";
    cin >> hgt1;

    x = lgt*hgt;
    y = lgt1*hgt1;

    if (x == y); {
        cout << "both is same" << endl;
    }   
    else if (x > y);{
        cout << "rectangle 1 is bigger" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "rectangle 2 is bigger" << endl;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

What is causing this error to happen?

Comment: The semicolon is used to *end* a statement, not to separate them.

Comment: For future reference, compiling with different compilers can give you varying errors, which can help to track something down. Also advised is [turning on warnings](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/41d7314fb66a9419). I got a fairly useful one relating to your problem. Ultimately, you might have to go back to your learning material and compare your if statements with theirs to find your syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an errant semicolon (`;`) in your first else condition.  The code should be changed to this:

```
else if (x > y) {
```

Answer (score 2):

It is syntacticly incorrect to have a semicolon after a boolean expression in a branch statement. The semicolon denotes the end of the statement, and so, the statement must be valid to close it.